# Can you call "require" on a variable?

Tags: module, lua, coronasdk

I have a lua file that will require another lua file to run but I can't hard code the file name. Can i use the require function on a variable or do i need to figure out an alternate approach to what i am doing?

For example

```
local path = "mypath.txt"

local level = require path
```

Comment: Note that `require` needs a *module name*, not a *path*. The searchers called by `require` convert module names to paths or whatever is needed.

Comment: Oh that brings up another question i have. Can you have multiple modules named the same thing in different locations and if so how do you get to each one?

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. `require "module"` is just a syntactic sugar for `require("module")` that only works if call a function with single argument that is a string or table constructor. Use proper call in form of `require(path)` and it will work.